# ¿Por que son 65535 puertos logicos?

Tags: puertos

Necesito saber de donde sale ese numero o por que ese hacerca de los puertos logicos, a que se debe esa cantidad de puertos logicos ?

Comment: El puerto se define como un entero sin signo (2 bytes) 2^16 = 65536 valor posibles, pero particularmente el port 0 esta reservado, entonces se hablan de  65535 puertos posibles.

Comment: Según wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking), A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to 65535 . Lo que viene siendo 2^16 --> 65536 posibilidades.

Comment: Haces una pregunta que solamente los diseñadores de TCP/IP podrían responder, ya que es una decisión arbitraria. Si bien te han comentado y respondido que es porque las cabeceras utilizan enteros de 16 bits, en realidad la relación es a la inversa. Las cabeceras y todo lo relacionado a puertos utilizan enteros de 16 bits, debido a que así fue decidido. Podrían utilizar enteros de 8 bits, de 32 o 64, es algo arbitrario y todos acá podemos hacer suposiciones de por qué tomaron esa decisión (yo tengo mi propia opinión), pero solamente ellos podrían responderlo con exactitud.

Comment: Efectivamente, la decisión de que hayan sido de `16 bits` fue un tanto *"arbitraria"*  para el año 1981 como el diseño de `IPv4`. Seguramente les pareció un número bastante considerable. Aunque no hemos tenido problema con la cantidad de puertos disponibles a diferencia de la cantidad de IP's en `IPv4`.

Answer (score 1):

Los protocolos [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) y [TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) llevan en sus cabeceras información fija entre ellas el *Puerto Origen* y el *Puerto Destino*. Ambas tienen una longitud fija de 16 bits (2 bytes) cada una.

- **Puerto Origen**: Entero de 16 bits sin signo.
- **Puerto Destino**: Entero de 16 bits sin signo.

Aquí una representación de una parte de la cabecera :

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|         Puerto Origen         |        Puerto Destino         |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
...
```

Tomando en cuenta lo anterior podemos observar que la cantidad de puertos disponibles van del 0 al 2^16 - 1 ya que 2^16 es la cantidad máxima de puertos disponibles en base 2 y cuya base es utilizada para representar estos valores.

Por ejemplo, esta es la secuencia de valores de 0 a 2^16 - 1:

```
(0000 0000 0000 0000) en base 2 = (    0) en base 10
(0000 0000 0000 0001) en base 2 = (    1) en base 10
....
(1111 1111 1111 1111) en base 2 = (65535) en base 10
```

Y como comentan el puerto 0 está reservado según la [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) aunque [SpeedGuide.net](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=0) también hace la siguiente nota:

> Este puerto es técnicamente ilegal, pero es posible. A menudo se utiliza para identificar máquinas, debido a que los diferentes sistemas operativos responden a este puerto de diferentes formas.